# Firebase Admin SDK - How to initialize with OAuth2 Refresh Token and communicate securely with web app?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm developing a web app (using [Angular](https://angular.io/)) which works with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com).

I installed the [ngx-auth-firebaseui](https://github.com/AnthonyNahas/ngx-auth-firebaseui) which is an easy to use library I used to perform user login. Since I need custom APIs I also developed an [ExpressJs](https://expressjs.com/) server that uses the Firebase Admin SDK.

I call ExpressJs APIs without any security for now (since I'm still in my local environment).

In order to use the Firebase Admin SDK, I followed the official docs, which say:

> Once you have created a Firebase project, you can initialize the SDK with an authorization strategy that combines your service account file together with Google Application Default Credentials.
>
> Firebase projects support Google service accounts, which you can use to call Firebase server APIs from your app server or trusted environment. If you're developing code locally or deploying your application on-premises, you can use credentials obtained via this service account to authorize server requests.
>
> [...]
> **When authorizing via a service account, you have two choices for providing the credentials to your application. You can either set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, or you can explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code.** The first option is more secure and is strongly recommended.

Locally I set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` property and everything is okay. Does this also need to be set in the production environment or is there another method?

I would also like to use OAuth2 to secure communication between the web app and the server APIs, but I don't know how to integrate it within the authentication flow.

In addition, Firebase docs state:

> The Admin SDKs also provide a credential which allows you to authenticate with a Google OAuth2 refresh token:

```
var refreshToken; // Get refresh token from OAuth2 flow

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.refreshToken(refreshToken),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

but if I do this I receive the error:

```
.../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:47
    var tmp = from[key] || from[alt];
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientId' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1: *Fireabase Admin SDK initialization -- How to handle locally vs. in production?*

**Answer**: Using the Firebase Admin SDK requires initialization in the local development environment as well as the production server environment. In both environments, you may either set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, or you may explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code.

---

## Question 2: *How to use OAuth2 for secure communications between Wep App and Server APIs?*

**Answer**: [**Verify Id Tokens**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)

> After a successful sign-in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the server, verify the integrity and authenticity of the ID token and retrieve the `uid` from it. You can use the `uid` transmitted in this way to securely identify the currently signed-in user on your server.

---

## Question 3: *How to authenticate with a Google OAuth2 refresh token using the Firebase Admin SDK?*

**Answer** from [**Manage User Sessions**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions)

> Firebase Authentication sessions are long lived. Every time a user
>   signs in, the user credentials are sent to the Firebase Authentication
>   backend and exchanged for a Firebase ID token (a JWT) and ***refresh
>   token***.

On the client (web app), the Firebase User has a [`refreshToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#refresh-token) property to retrieve the current refresh token.

However, the standard approach to initialize the Admin SDK is to either set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable or explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I manage JWT tokens validation successfully. I still don't understand the refreshToken usage, I see that the user has it inside the webapp.. should I send it to server and do something there? Or is it ok just to use JWT tokens in order to validate every request between webapp and server? Thanks

Comment: On the web client, you would call [`getIdToken(forceRefresh?: boolean)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#getidtoken) and pass `forceRefresh` equal to `true`. The ID Token is used to validate server requests. Another option, is to use [`Session Cookies`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) rather than passing the `ID Token` for each request.